# What mechanism would be needed to contain and inject super-heated plasma into a target?

Tags: technology, physics, weapons, combat, temperature

Two days ago, I [proposed a design](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/114384/what-are-the-practicalities-and-impracticalities-of-ultraheated-forearm-mounted) for dual forearm-mounted super-heated stabbing blades composed of a Titanium-Coltan alloy and capable of reaching 1,000 °C. These arm-blades were intended to act as secondary regeneration-negating weapons for a robot  designed to fight a person with the powers of [electrokinesis](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ShockAndAwe) and 
[Low-Mid regeneration](http://vsbattles.wikia.com/wiki/Regeneration).

A well thought-out response from [Blade Wraith](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/50282/blade-wraith) outlined that this weapon would have major issues with heat transference. They suggested an alternative which featured the blades containing super-heated plasma (around 8,000°C or 10,000°C) that is vented into a target upon being stabbed, [melting their internal organs](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CruelandUnusualDeath).

These new blades are made from [Adamantine](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/FantasyMetals) ([a stupidly-named fictional alloy many times stronger and lighter than titanium](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/WebAnimation/DeathBattle)), which can resist temperatures going into the quintuple range. However, there's just one problem: what sort of mechanism would be needed to contain the plasma and inject it into a target's body?

Comment: Wait... didn't I read this question yesterday or this morning?  Was the original deleted?  It's the phrase "A well thought-out response from Blade Wraith..."  Serious deja-vu.  Why are we asking the question again?  Anyway, either create the plasma JIT (Just In TIme, a business term) or hold it in a magnetic bottle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Magnetic Containment**

Your spikes are actually not making or containing the plasma. They are plasma rail guns that are simply meant to accelerate the plasma into the target after penetrating it. The problem with plasma in-atmosphere is that trying to fire it from a plasma cannon wouldn't work (fyi plasma cannons are just rail guns accelerating a quantity of plasma instead of a slug.) A plasma "bolt" would be awesome at messing with some guy's regeneration, but due to "blooming" any plasmoid like a bolt or toroid or even a plasma beam would dissipate in atmosphere within only a few meters making it useless as a ranged weapon. This robot has these spike shaped magnetic accelerators that essentially blast a plasma beam into the enemy being at extremely high velocity adding an pretty stout kinetic punch to the hot stabby bits. These spikes are connected to a reaction chamber within the body of the robot that are then channeled through magnetically contained conduits and given a final boost by the super-conducting electromagnets housed inside this spike. The spike itself still gets incredibly hot due to radiant heat but the plasma itself isn't ever actually touching anything except the target.

Whats really cool is that at-least within a few meters it also acts like a really really hot flame thrower/giant blowtorch.